# そして、子供は、そういう大人の生活の知恵を敏感に知っていて。。。

Tags: meaning

そして、子供は、そういう大人の生活の知恵を敏感に知っていて。。。

I am trying to understand the passage, can someone validate my translation:
"...therefore the kids are sensitive to the wisdom life and they know it of the beforementioned adult?"

Take 2:
"Kids are quick to understand the wisdom of such an adult's lifestyle"

amirite?

Comment: Bulk translation checks are off-topic here. And please check if you copied it correctly. Isn't it を that comes after 知恵? And where did that "if" come from?

Comment: Is this a machine translation?

Comment: @Leebo  Yes I am a machine from the future

Comment: @naruto  is this correct: Kids are quick to understand the wisdom of such an adult's lifestyle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> そして、子供は、そういう大人の生活の知恵を敏感に知っていて。。。
> ...therefore the kids are sensitive to the wisdom life and they know it of the beforementioned adult

It seems you're not parsing the sentence correctly.

How about parsing it like this:

> そして、子供は、そういう（大人の）「生活の知恵」を（敏感に）知っていて。。。

そういう modifies the noun phrase 生活の知恵 "wisdom in living".
敏感に modifies the verb phrase 知っていて.

Subject = 子供 children
Object = そういう（大人の）生活の知恵 adults' such wisdom in living
Verb = （敏感に）知っている are sensitively aware of / sensitively learn

Comment: Is this correct: Kids are quick to understand the wisdom of such an adult's lifestyle

Comment: @fynxgloire そういう is probably modifying 生活の知恵, not 大人. "Kids sensitively understand such a wisdom of life (of adults) and ..."